# position:sticky header on a page with content that is taller than body's height, what should I do to make it work?

Tags: css

On this page below, when you start scrolling, the header works as expected, it sticks to the top.

But if you keep scrolling down, the header will be out.

But if there is something very tall on this page, the header will not stick to the top of the  - which is reasonable according to what sticky is defined.

However, since many pages are unsure of the body's total heigh, what can I do to make the header work without wrapping it into another container with the `.long-div` together?

```css
.sticky{position:sticky; background:#efe; top:0}

body {margin:0; padding:0; height:3000px; background:radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);}

.long-div {height:4000px}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">header</div>

<div class="long-div">
 Content with height more than body's 3000px;
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `position:sticky`, header can't go outside of its parent.

[image]

You can remove the height of body.

```css
.sticky{position:sticky; background:#efe; top:0}

body {margin:0; padding:0; background:radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);}

.long-div {height:4000px}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">header</div>

<div class="long-div">
 Content with height more than body's 3000px;
</div>
```

Or try `position:fixed`:

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #efe;
  top: 0
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  height: 3000px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 1) 35%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.long-div {
  height: 4000px
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">header</div>

<div class="long-div">
  Content with height more than body's 3000px;
</div>
```